# Designing REST API for duplicate calls

Tags: android, api, rest

When designing a REST-ful API, do I need to handle client connectivity status?

For example: in Android, the user wants to send billing details to his email. He clicks "Send" button, the app goes to call API endpoint. At some point before the API returns a response, the app loses its network connectivity. Meanwhile, the transaction on the server-side (sending bill details to the user's email) is already done. The user doesn't know that and he clicks the "Send" button again. Later when he checks the email, there are 2 emails for billing details.

Now I understand that for transactions such as shopping basket, the client needs to include a transaction ID in the request body to make it idempotent. But, do I need to use that method for other API calls?

Comment: You can also check whether your previous request was successful or not? Also you can put a flag in your DB for that transaction like whether mail sent for this bill nor not. So when you send current request and you know previous request was unsuccessful, you can make a call to API for that transaction and check whether it was successful or not

Comment: "You can also check whether your previous request was successful or not" which means, using a transaction ID generated by client? That's what I was asking about. Should I think about that little detail? Because I'm developing _the_ Android client and the API developer doesn't think it's too important to think about duplicate calls in case there's a network loss.

Comment: What you can do is, you can simply generate an ID (`UUID.randomUUID().toString()`) and send it with request. Store your request and next time without generating new session, check whether it is already processed or not

Comment: Depends on the request.  For sending an email, the worst case is two emails, no big deal.  For something that can cost him money, like placing an order, yes you do.

Comment: you can use throttleFirst() in RxJava. simple button multi click event control.